# Minimagick error: libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable

Tags: imagemagick, minimagick, mogrify

I am trying to do a bulk conversion of photos using MiniMagick / ImageMagick / mogrify and I keep on seeing:

`libgomp: Thread creation failed: Resource temporarily unavailable`

It processes the first 500 or so photos fine, and then seems to be stalled on photo #494 out of 3093.

Does anyone know why this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found using the [posix-spawn](https://github.com/rtomayko/posix-spawn) gem fixed this for me as explained in [the MiniMagick docs](https://github.com/minimagick/minimagick#errnoenomem):

```rb
MiniMagick.configure do |config|
  config.shell_api = "posix-spawn"
end
```

So I think this was memory related, but was reported with a cryptic error message.

Answer (score 0):

Put MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1 before the command. For example, instead of

```
mogrify -verbose -path 800px-wide -resize '800>' -quality 20% originals/$1*
```

do

```
MAGICK_THREAD_LIMIT=1 mogrify -verbose -path 800px-wide -resize '800>' -quality 20% originals/$1*
```